# How to create a StreamProvider and subscribe to it later, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an issue where I want to create a `MultiProvider` with some different providers, the problem is that two of those are StreamProviders that require first to have a firebase auth login, and after that subscribe to a Stream in firebase based on the result of the user logged in.

So if I cannot launch the `StreamProvider` before the login at the top of my `MaterialApp`.

If I declare those providers after the login is complete I get an error that the provider is not on the correct route because I need the data in several routes around all my app.

Here is my code:

```
class Neybor extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = GoogleFonts.nunito;
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(create: (context) => new Data()),

        /// Settings Stream
        StreamProvider<SettingsDataModel>.value(
          value: Globals.firebaseCaller.settings(),
        ),

        /// Plans Stream
        StreamProvider<PlansDataModel>.value(
          value: Globals.firebaseCaller.plans(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
...
}
```

For `Globals.firebaseCaller.settings()` and `Globals.firebaseCaller.plans()` I use the register user uid

Is there a way to declare a `StreamProvider` and subscribe to it later on my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: User the default constructor instead of the ".value"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `create` parameter in the `StreamProvider` to pass your stream and subscribe to it using `Provider.of<T>(context)`

```
class Neybor extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = GoogleFonts.nunito;
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        /// Settings Stream
        /// Globals.firebaseCaller.settings() should returns a Stream<SettingsDataModel>
        StreamProvider<SettingsDataModel>(create: (context) =>
          Globals.firebaseCaller.settings(), 
        ),
      ],
      child: HomeView()
..
```

then in the HomeView()

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    SettingsDataModel settings = Provider.of<SettingsDataModel>(context);

    if (settings == null) {
      return Align(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      // your code
      ...
    }
...
```