# Provider with loading widget in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a stream provider in my Flutter app which fetches data from my Firestore database.

I want to show a loading widget while loading the data until it is done loading. Similar to the Futurebuilder with the ConnectionState function for example.

Is this possible?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a StreamProvider and subscribe to it later, Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404845/how-to-create-a-streamprovider-and-subscribe-to-it-later-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a future builder you can check if your snapshot.data is null. If it is null you show the spinner, otherwise you show your content:

```
StreamBuilder(
   stream: myStream, //YOUR STREAM
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     return snapshot.data == null
       ? Spinner() //LOADING SPINNER
       : Container() //AFTER RETRIEVING CONTENT

   }
)
```

**UPDATE**

Since you mentioned Future builder I got mislead. This is the answer you are searching for:

[How to create a StreamProvider and subscribe to it later, Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404845/how-to-create-a-streamprovider-and-subscribe-to-it-later-flutter)

Comment: You wrote code for the StreamBuilder but i meant the StreamProvider

Comment: Answer updated.