# I'm using multiprovider in my app with streamBuilder.value(), the provider to get the data only if I restart the app or hot reload

Tags: firebase, flutter

Here the `StreamProvider<UserInfoModel>` is causing an error:

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/models/categorywise/product_category_list_model.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/models/milk_product_model.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/models/milk_quantity_list_model.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/models/user_info_model.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/services/authentication_services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/services/database_services/database_service.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/services/location_services.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/services/shared_preference_service.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );
  SharedPreferenceServices.settingPreference();
  runApp(Phoenix(child: const MyApp()));
  await LocationServices().checkingServiceAvailability();
  await LocationServices().gettingPermission();
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Location location = Location();
  LocationData? locationData;

  _MyAppState() {
    gettingLocData().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        locationData = val;
      });
    });
  }

  gettingLocData() async {
    return await location.getLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();
    ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = ConnectivityResult.none;
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$locationData');
    print(connectivityResult.toString());
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User?>.value(
          value: AuthServices().userLoginStream,
          initialData: null,
        ),
        StreamProvider<List<ProductDairyCategoryListModel>>.value(
          value: DatabaseServices(category: "").ProductCategoryListStream,
          initialData: [],
        ),
        StreamProvider<UserInfoModel?>.value(
          value: DatabaseServices().cartDetailsStream,
          initialData: null,
        ),
        StreamProvider.value(
          value: location.onLocationChanged,
          initialData: locationData,
        ),
        StreamProvider<MilkQuantityListModel?>.value(
          value: DatabaseServices().listOfMilkQuantityStream,
          initialData: null,
        ),
        StreamProvider<MilkProductModel?>.value(

          value: DatabaseServices().milkProductStream,
           initialData: null)
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            buttonColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
            opacity: 1,
            size: 16,
          ),
        ),
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the screen where I am reading the data. where I am getting null.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/models/milk_product_model.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/models/user_info_model.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/screens/milk_screen.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/screens/order_history_screen.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:milk_groceries_delivery_app/screens/search_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  const Tabs({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TabsState createState() => _TabsState();
}

class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabsController;

  MilkProductModel? listOfFuturesOfDocumentRef;
  UserInfoModel? userInfoModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _tabsController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _tabsController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double heightScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    listOfFuturesOfDocumentRef = Provider.of<MilkProductModel?>(context);
    userInfoModel = Provider.of<UserInfoModel?>(context);

    print(listOfFuturesOfDocumentRef?.listOfDocumentReference);
    print(userInfoModel?.cart);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabsController,
          children: [
            HomeScreen(),
            SearchScreen(),
            OrderHistoryScreen(),
            ProfileScreen(),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 0.07 * heightScreen,
          child: BottomAppBar(
            shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            child: TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,
              indicatorColor: Colors.green,
              labelColor: Colors.green,
              controller: _tabsController,
              tabs: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color:
                      _tabsController.index == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_bag,
                  color:
                      _tabsController.index == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.update_sharp,
                  color:
                      _tabsController.index == 2 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color:
                      _tabsController.index == 3 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => MilkScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            'Milk',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the UserInfoModel which i defined.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserInfoModel {
  GeoPoint? location;
  List? cart;
  List? orders;
  // String? name;
  List? address;
  String? phonenumber;
  String? email;
  List<dynamic> listOfMilkQuantity;
  String? profileImageUrl;
  UserInfoModel({
    required this.cart,
    required this.location,
    required this.orders,
    this.address,
    this.email,
    // this.name,
    this.phonenumber,
    required this.listOfMilkQuantity,
    required this.profileImageUrl,
  });
}
```

The stream gives null value and then works perfect once I hot reload or restart. I don't know why that's the case. Is there any other alternative for doing this?
Your help is highly appreciated. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Please check your links. The second one is broken. Seems that you putted the last part into the last line by accident.

Comment: Yes, it should be visible now.

Comment: Please copy your code instead of uploading an image.

Comment: Done! Uploaded the code instead of image

Answer (score 0):

*[Here](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/stream-provider) is a great example on how to work with `Stream` and `StreamProvider`*

Also see this question: [How to create a StreamProvider and subscribe to it later, Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63404845/7834341)

Try to use `StreamaProvider` default constructor and put your stream into the `create` field, like described in the linked article. Instead of the `StreamProvider.value` constructor.

```
StreamProvider<SettingsDataModel>(
  create: (context) => Globals.firebaseCaller.settings(), 
),
```

And just a hint: Use extension functions. You can simply use: `context.watch<T>()` instead of `Provider.of<T>(context)`

And you can also write your own extensions, so you can use `context.height` instead of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`.

Comment: Thankyou so much sir! This helped me a lot and the hints were something new I learnt.

Comment: Perfect! Glad to hear that! Would be great if you can accept the answer then! If you need further help, don't hesitate to contact me.